# Use all cores to make OpenCV 3

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, compilation, multicore

How can I force the ubuntu 16.04 to use all the cores to compile or make opencv 3?

I have found a website to change a cmake file called OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake, on this blog https://iamsrijon.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/how-to-compile-opencv-to-utilize-multiple-core-processor-in-linux/

But it did not work! Maybe because I have already TBB

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: `make -j N_CORES`?

Comment: Thanks! That worked! how could I find this?